# Are there any project status/dashboard applications for github?

Tags: github, dashboard

We've recently moved our code hosting to github. I want to set-up a dashboard display to the rotation of key stats pages we have on the team's local TV. I've already done a bit of searching for project dashboards for github although it was mostly stymied by the number of other project dashboards that are hosted on github.

Options I'm considering:

- Using the RSS news feed and Google feed API
- Creating a new "read-only" github user and just putting the github page on rotation (although this may violate TOS?)

However before I do that t would be good to know if there are any existing dashboards available for github?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't necessarily need a dashboard with features viewable only on GitHub (such as issues, wiki, pull requests, pretty activity/network graphs etc.), but can be satisfied with simpler features regarding the git repository itself, you could clone the repository locally and host it via [Gitweb or one of it alternatives](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb) on a local Apache server. All of these web interfaces have their own dashboards, one of these may fit your liking.

Keeping the repository up-to-date could be done locally with a periodic job or with a [Github repository hook](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/).

Comment: So I have set up a mirror of the github repository which displays a cgit summary. However it would be nice to see pull activity as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across http://octoboard.com/ - might be able to fork it and make it work for you.